# Do I need to arrange the links under XML Sitemap?

Tags: seo, wordpress, yoast

We use Yoast on WordPress website and it generates a https://www.website.com/page-sitemap.xml, arranged base on the last date of modification.

Do we need to have arranged it base on our navigation menu?

Comment: No.  Sitemaps aren't really used by Google anymore.  Also sitemaps are completely unrelated to your menu structure.  Read https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Order does not matter in a sitemap.

From sitemaps.org:

> Q: Does position of a URL in a Sitemap influence its use?
>
> No. The position of a URL in the Sitemap is not likely to impact how it is used or regarded by search engines.
>
> https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_url_position

From Google:

> the order in the sitemap file doesn't matter at all.
>
> (John Mueller, Google Employee)
>
> https://www.seroundtable.com/google-sitemaps-url-order-does-not-matter-25896.html